# How do I decorate a property with DispId (both get and set? neither?)

Tags: c#, com

```
   [DispId(8)]
    DateTime MaxDate { [DispId(8)] get; [DispId(8)] set; }
```

Should the get and the set have different DispIds, since they're two different functions? or should I just decorate the method name once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a property should have only one [DispId], applied to the property declaration.  The client code indicates whether it wants to call the getter or setter by passing either DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET or DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT for the wFlags argument in the [IDispatch::Invoke()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call.

It is not that it is drastically wrong to repeat the [DispId] on both the getter and setter, and Tlbexp.exe supports that, it just doesn't make much sense to do it that way.  Using *different* dispids is technically possible but pretty much guaranteed to make the client code fail because it won't expect that.